# How to compare Shared versus VPS hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, vps, shared-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

While shopping around for a new hosting service, I have find that I have no idea how to decide between shared hosting (which I presently use for *all* my sites) service or go towards virtual (VPS) hosting which are always much more expensive. The real question is **How to determine when shared hosting is no longer an option for a site?**

PS: [This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20687/shared-versus-vps-versus-cloud) covers some similar ground but is too specific for my needs.

Comment: Even though this isn't specifically a hosting request, Nick's answer goes into good detail shared vs vps. Plus we need to keep question related to choosing hosting in one place so it is a resource for everyone researching hosting.

Comment: I read Nick answer and, while nice for the other question, is not what I am looking for: Facts to consider in order to determine that shared hosting is not enough for a site.

Answer (score 0):

VPS usually implies that you have someone on staff who can manage server tasks.  What if you need to upgrade php, or something fails and you need to restore from a backup?
If you generally expect the hosting company to keep things up to date on the backend, then stick with shared hosting.

also see this post
[shared vs dedicated hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/154/shared-vs-dedicated-hosting)

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer the question at all. I know what these are. What I need to know is how to compare them from the perspective of the website and how it uses resources.

Comment: There are a lot of factors to consider, the first being whether you have resources to manage a server. You shouldn't go any further with VPS  as an option if you don't have those resources.